# Строковой тип в языке C. Как правильно создать строку?

Tags: c, строки

Я читал, что строкового типа в языке C нет, и все строки - это массивы символов. Т. е. нам нужно обязательно определять размер этого массива; если строка изменяется, то и с размером массива надо что-то делать и т. п. Поэтому работать со строками в C заметно сложнее, чем в языках, где строковый тип есть.

Но вот я объявляю переменную, в которой хочу хранить, пока неизвестный, текст, который будет изменяться далее в программе, следующим образом:

```
char *s;
```

И далее я присваиваю этой переменной значение:

```
s = "abcde";
```

А потом (в другом месте программы) присваиваю ей же новое значение:

```
s = "zyxwvutsrq";
```

Ну и т. д.

Программа выполняется, значение `s` меняется без проблем. Не могу понять, в чем тогда сложность работы со строками? В том, что нет завершающего `'\0'`? Но зачем он нужен, если все и так работает как надо (в т. ч. `strlen` показывает правильное значение)?

---

Вот этот фрагмент РАБОТАЕТ. Содержимое s меняется как надо. Strlen тоже показывает правильную информацию. Более того, к отдельным символам s можно обращаться как к массиву - по индексам s[0], s[1], ... Символы выводятся верно. В общем, вопрос остается: зачем работать со строками как-то по-другому, если так - очень просто и все вроде работает? Очень прошу объяснить, а то я перехожу на Си с другого языка, где такого вопроса не было, и не могу найти в инете ответ...

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *s;

    s = "abcde";
    printf("5: %s :%i (%i)\n", s, strlen(s), sizeof(s));
    s = "ab";
    printf("2: %s :%i (%i)\n", s, strlen(s), sizeof(s));
    s = "abcdefghijk";
    printf("11: %s :%i (%i)\n", s, strlen(s), sizeof(s));
    s = "";
    printf("0: %s :%i (%i)\n", s, strlen(s), sizeof(s));
    s = "abc";
    printf("3: %s :%i (%i)\n", s, strlen(s), sizeof(s));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?rls=org.mozilla%3Aru%3Aunofficial&ei=29_KXZmoCefzqwGMpK24Dg&q=%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%B2+%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5+C&oq=%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%B2+%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5+C

Comment: Полный ответ не напишу, но рекомендую поискать по словам «Чем отличаются стек (_stack_), куча (_heap_), и статические переменные (_static storage_)».

Comment: ну на самом деле тут всё сложнее. У вас не char * а на самом деле const char *. И менять там что либо будет опасно. Вы меняете не саму строку, а указатель на неё.

Comment: `char = *s` - это какая-то белиберда.

Comment: Если так хранить строки, вы не сможете их менять. Если это не нужно, то такой способ подходит. *"нет завершающего '\0'"* Нет, он тут есть.

Comment: Как вы сами правильно сказали, строки в С - это массивы символов. `char *s` - это не массив символов. Это указатель. Поэтому `char *s` - это ни в коем случае не строка. `char *s` может быть указателем на строку, но не самой строкой. Все, что вы делаете с `s` - это работа с указателем на строку, а не с самой строкой. К работе с самой строкой все это не имеет никакого отношения. А вопросы, которые вы подняли в тексте - это вопросы работы с самой строкой. Это совсем другая тема.

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваши ответы, но я все равно не понимаю: присваивание переменной s любого нового значения приводит к тому, что обращение к этой переменной выводит это значение. То есть программа ведет себя в точности как можно было ожидать, скажем, от VB: присваиваешь строковой переменной значение и далее с ним работаешь без проблем. В приведенном мною примере делается то же самое, все работает... В чем смысл? :)

Comment: Попробуйте теперь _изменить_ строку: добавить к ней символы, удалить, заменить...

Comment: *"зачем работать со строками как-то по-другому"* Говорю же, такие строки нельзя изменять. (По одному символу, то есть.)

Comment: Вроде как на С написано 1000000000 велосипедов касаемо string in c ... google - custom string in c

Answer (score 4):

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
char *s;

s = "apple";
s = "banana";
s = "";
s = "orange";
```

Начнем с того, что, как вы правильно заметили, в языке C нет строкового типа. Строки определяются на уровне стандартной библиотеки языка:

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and
>   including the first null character.

Самое интересное — в следующем предложении:

> A *pointer to a string* is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed)
>   character.

Теперь должно быть понятно, что `s` — это не строка, а *указатель* на строку<sup>1</sup>.

Для дальнейших рассуждений нам нужно познакомится с понятием *строкового литерала*:

> A *character string literal* is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in double-quotes, as in `"xyz"`.

Получается, что в нашем примере есть 4 различных строковых литерала<sup>2</sup> (строки<sup>3</sup>) и один указатель на строку, который указывает на каждую из этих строк по очереди.

Сами строки нигде не меняются. Изменение строковых литералов запрещено, так как является неопределенным поведением:

```
char *s = "cat";

s[0] = 'r'; // Неопределенное поведение!
```

Поэтому нам нужен какой-то способ создания *изменяемых* строк. Для этого достаточно просто создать массив символов, последний элемент которого — нуль-терминатор:

```
char s[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

Можно выделить память динамически (если мы, например, захотим поменять размер строки):

```
char *s = malloc(4); // s — указатель на область памяти размером в 4 байта.
s[0] = 'a'; 
s[1] = 'b';
s[2] = 'c';
s[3] = '\0'; // Теперь s — указатель на строку.
```

Также C позволяет инициализировать массивы строковыми литералами:

```
char s[] = "abc"; // В s будет записано {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}.
```

При этом, строковой литерал `"abc"` и строка `s` — это абсолютно *разные* сущности.

---

<sup>1.</sup> <sup>Формально, `s` — это указатель на `char`, но он становится указателем на строку, когда мы присваиваем ему строковой литерал.</sup>

<sup>2.</sup> <sup>Кстати говоря, в каждом строковом литерале есть завершающий нуль-терминатор `\0`. Он добавляется автоматически в одной из стадий трансляции.</sup>

<sup>3.</sup> <sup>Строковой литерал не всегда является строкой, но в нашем примере все строковые литералы — строки.</sup>

Comment: Все, вопрос закрыт. Большое спасибо всем, кто помог разобраться, и особенно eanmos!
Я понял, что как я написал в первом сообщении делать плохо потому что: а) в статической памяти по мере "изменения" содержимого s просто накапливаются все новые строковые литералы (а старые никуда не исчезают); б) невозможно изменять отдельные символы внутри этих строковых литералов.
Теперь все ясно :)

Comment: *"...в статической памяти по мере "изменения" содержимого s просто накапливаются все новые строковые литералы..."* Вы что-то не поняли. Никакие строковые литералы "по мере изменения" нигде не накапливаются. Все строковые литералы вашей программы существуют сразу, с момента ее запуска и до момента ее завершения. Можно также сказать, что все строковые литералы создаются еще на стадии компиляции.